# Как запретить UPDATE если не совпали интервалы?

Tags: mysql, update

В таблице строки сгенерированы изначально (список пин-кодов) и далее только обновляются два поля: статус status (с 0 на 1 и обратно) и поле номер заказа ord_id, для продажи одного или нескольких пин-кодов делаю банальный апдейт, а для продажи нескольких пин-кодов с определенными ID (подряд идущая серия) в одном заказе делаю так:

```
UPDATE pin_codes SET status=1, ord_id=223344 WHERE status=0 AND (id BETWEEN 300 AND 345)
```

Если все запрошенные пин-коды уже проданы (статус=1), то обновления не произойдет, все ок.
Если все запрошенные пин-коды свободны, то тоже все ок - произойдет апдейт как положено.
**Вопрос**: как запретить апдейт, если часть из запрашиваемого интервала пин-кодов уже продана, то есть по сути обновится только часть строк.
Смысл в том, что продажа по сериям, но разные клиенты выбирают разные серии, для кого-то подходит серия от 300 до 345, для кого-то от 300 до 400, для кого-то от 320 до 350 и так далее и обязательно полнота серии.
Шальную мысль сначала делать select и затем по результатам update сразу выкинул....
**То есть если упрощенно, то разрешать делать апдейт только при полном выполнений всех условий**

Comment: То есть если упрощенно, то разрешать делать апдейт только при полном выполнений всех условий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте подзапрос для проверки:

```
UPDATE pin_codes SET status=1, ord_id=223344 
WHERE not exists
                (select 1 from 
                   (select * from pin_codes 
                             where (id between 300 and 345) and status=1
                   ) a
                ) 
AND (id BETWEEN 300 AND 345)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee4d9/1
UPD. В MySql нужно слегка костылить, поправил ответ.

Comment: Что будет, если у id 300 status будет модифицирован с 0 на 1. Потом запрос возьмётся модифицировать 301-ый. Подзапрос какой status увидит у 300-го? Старый 0 или новый 1? Ведь если будет 1, то тогда такая метода модифицирует ровно одну запись и на этом всё закончится.

Comment: Модифицирует все. Фиддл добавил

Comment: где-то читал, что MySQL перед апдейтом получает всю нужную информацию, вот как бы ее тоже получить без лишнего подзапроса и пустить в обработку? и еще - возможны ли временные коллизии в вашем варианте, то есть когда почти одновременно обратятся несколько пользователей?

Comment: ок, все работает! запрос на 1млн строк выполняется 0.1665 сек, неплохо, но есть куда двигаться. я думаю, если у меня MyISAM, то таблица будет заблочена полностью на весь этот запрос и временных коллизий не будет априори?